# Chrome taking 90% CPU in the background

Tags: google-chrome, cpu, cpu-usage

Whenever I boot up my PC and open task manager Chrome is shown to be taking 90% cpu with no active windows open, this is just something in the background. I have tried:

- reinstalling Chrome
- disabling all extensions
- checked chrome's task manager, the process is not listed

Please help, also for some reason when I click the 3 dots then at the bottom it says "managed by your organization" even though this is a personal PC for personal use only.

Comment: Gave you tried flushing your browser cache?

Comment: I'd suspect malware - https://malwaretips.com/blogs/remove-managed-by-your-organisation-virus/

Comment: the cache is less than 68MB so I did not think that could have the problem

Comment: is the "managed by the organization" related to the high cpu usage?

Comment: Running something nasty in the background whilst simultaneously locking you out from disabling it is standard malware practise.

Comment: i read another answer here and found "f_00002d" named file on my pc. It is in the App data of both Edge and Chrome, should I delete it?

Comment: Get a decent antivirus - by design they make themselves hard to delete

Comment: Try: https://www.f-secure.com/en/home/free-tools/online-scanner

Comment: I installed Malwarebytes and it detected the files causing the problem of cpu usage, it deleted them and now that is fixed. However, Chrome still has the "managed by the organization" issue. I read somewhere that in recent Windows 10 updates it is normal. So, I do not think it is of any major concern right now.

Comment: Removing the malware will not reset the prefs it changed.

Comment: So, are you suggesting to reinstall Chrome again?

Comment: Reinstalling will not change anything - it almost never does unless you fully clean out all the old prefs etc. See - https://superuser.com/q/100360/347380

Comment: Check if you still have any policies set in chrome:policy

Comment: checked chrome://policy, apart from Google Update Policies which have policy values there is an "ExtensionInstallForcelist" which has no Policy value. Here are the details for the same.

`ExtensionInstallForcelist

Platform
Machine
Mandatory
OK`